# Rewriting second order differential equations into first order and using with Euler Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, runge-kutta-methods

I'm working with the Schrodinger equation

$$\frac{-\hbar ^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x^2}=E \psi$$

and trying to use the Euler Method to approximate a wavefunction. The SEQ can be rewritten as

$$\psi '' = -\frac{2mE}{\hbar ^2}\psi$$

My question is 2-fold: How do I rewrite the SEQ as a set of first order differential equations? Am I using Euler Method correctly?

**My attempt:**

I think it is this, but I'm not sure:

Let $w=\psi '$ and $w' = \psi ''$. Now we have

$$w' = \frac{-2mE}{\hbar ^2}\psi$$

and to use Euler method it is

$$w_{i+1} = w_i + hw' \to \psi_{i+1}'=\psi_i'+h\psi_i''$$

$$\psi_{i+1}=\psi_i + hw \to \psi_{i+1} = \psi_i + h\psi_{i+1}'$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
It's convenient to rewrite the original equation as two first order ones. Namely,
$$
\varphi'\pars{x} = -k^{2}\psi\pars{x}\,,\quad
\psi'\pars{x} = \varphi\pars{x}\,;\qquad k^{2} = {2mE \over h^{2}}
$$
\begin{align}
\totald{}{x}{\psi\pars{x} \choose \varphi\pars{x}} =
\underbrace{\pars{\begin{array}{cc}
\ds{0} & \ds{1}
\\
\ds{-k^{2}} & \ds{0}
\end{array}}}_{\ds{\mathsf{A}}}\ \underbrace{%
{\psi\pars{x} \choose \varphi\pars{x}}}_{\ds{\Psi\pars{x}}} \implies
\Psi\,'\pars{x} = \mathsf{A}\Psi\pars{x}
\end{align}

---

$$
\bbx{\ds{\Psi_{n + 1} = \Psi_{n} + h\,\mathsf{A}\Psi_{n}\,,\qquad Euler}}
$$

Comment: So then how do I get the 2nd derivatives? Is it just $\varphi _{n+1}' = -k^2 \psi _{n}$? Are my subscripts correct here?

Comment: @loltospoon Whenever you finish the whole iteration, you can recover the last values of $\psi_{N}$ and $\varphi_{N}$ from the last $\Psi_{N}$.

Comment: Wait, I'm not quite sure what you mean. By "the whole iteration", do you mean my evaluation of $\psi$ and $\varphi$ on the entire interval $[a,b]$?

Comment: @loltospoon Yes. You start at some point $x_{0}$ and, by increasing $n$, you'll arrive to arrive to any point you want.